# Listactivity black screen with title 

Tags: java, android, listactivity

I have ListActivity consist of many rows ,  every thing runs fine ,when first run of App it show black screen for ( 1 second ) before show the listactivity screen , in this black screen on top left corner it appear the title name of application which we set it in begining of creating new eclipse project as image below:

[image]

please if you have any advice how to remove :

**The black screen which appear for ( 1 second ) before show the listactivity screen with its title .**

i know this title will be also the name of app which appear in app icon in the device 
just i want to

**remove the black screen with its title** ,

so when lunch the App it show directly the listactivity screen as  below :

[image]

Listactivity code :

```
 public class Menu extends ListActivity {

  String classes[] = { "First Item", "Second Item", "Third Item", "Fourth
      Item", "Fifth Item"};

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    ListView lv = getListView();   
    lv.setCacheColorHint(0);  
    lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fall);
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

                   }
  @Override
   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
     String cheese = classes[position];

   try {
   Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.test.demo.MyItem");
   Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
   ourIntent.putExtra("cheese", cheese);
   startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); }}}
```

Thanks in advance .

**UPDATE :**

Applying full screen to menu activity in the manifest will solve the problem as this:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

but i already assign custom theme to menu activity in manifest as this :

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme_menu"
```

so how can i assign the above two theme together to menu activity in the same time .

Comment: declare it as fullscreen in the manifest

Comment: @njzk2 do you mean just write this in manifest :android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

Comment: @njzk2 i already assign custom theme to menu activity in manifest as this : android:theme="@style/Theme_menu" , how can i apply full screen too in manifest , please help.

Comment: I think `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` is the correct one, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it seems that you just need to make your `Theme_menu` to be derived from Android's `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`. To do this, modify your style XML by adding a `parent` attribute:

```
<style
    name="Theme_menu"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

    <!-- your style modifications for Theme_menu here -->

</style>
```

With the above change, you will most like would not need to have these lines in your Activity's `onCreate()` method (since it's set by the theme):

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```